# Is checking a double for equality ever safe?

Tags: java, floating-point

I have the following code:

```
double x = 0;

{ ...do stuff ...}

if(x == 0){

}
```

I was always taught that you shouldn't check floats for equality. Is checking to see if it is equal to zero any different?

Comment: i don t understand, if you init x to 0 why it is not good to check if 0 ? 0 is a valid value for double

Comment: Floating point numbers have a lot of rounding when you start to reach the limits. Same reason that if you have 3 digits to use in base ten, you have .004 and divide by three, you expect .001, but who knows what happens.

Comment: Thomas's corrections: It's technically not rounding, but inaccuracy due to the limited precision and the binary nature of floats.

Comment: Someone should summarize all the answers in this question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The reason you shouldn't check floats for equality is that floating point numbers are not perfectly precise -- there's some inaccuracy in storage with some numbers, such as those that extended too far into the mantissa and repeating decimals (note that I'm talking about repeating decimals in base 2). You can think of this imprecision as "rounding down". The digits that extend beyond the precision of the floating-point number are truncated, effectively rounding down.

If it has not changed, it will keep that equality. However, if you change it even slightly, you probably should not use equalities, but instead a range like `(x < 0.0001 && x > -.0001)`.

In short: as long as you're not playing with x at a very small level, it's OK.

Comment: It's not rounding that's going on, but the inability to store certain numbers due to the representation of floating point numbers. 0 can be exactly represented by a floating point value, but not all values can. 0.1, for example, has to be approximated.

Comment: @Thomas Rounding down. Same reason that `3/2` is `1`

Comment: No, not rounding. Imprecisions in IEEE floating point representations. Has absolutely nothing to do with rounding at all. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: Same thing @Thomas. Would you say `3/2` is `1` because of "imprecisions in the integer representations"? See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf) pg173, or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding)

Comment: @tennenrishin it is due to imprecision, in a sense. 3/2= 1.5, but integer division is only precise up to the decimal point, making it 1.

Comment: Yeah, and it has absolutely nothing to do with rounding at all. Except that it is [called rounding](https://www.google.com/search?q=floating+point+rounding+error) (even [in the article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding) linked by @Thomas).

Comment: Should I decrease the epsilon range if I know that the log10 of all my doubles are somewhere below, say, -5?

Comment: Or should I compare the log rather than the absolute value of the numbers?

Comment: @PEMapModder I'm not sure why that would help you? I suppose if you have the log handy you could, but I don't see any reason it would be better to use the log than the raw value.

Answer (score 17):

It is safe if the 0 you're trying to catch is the original 0 set at initialization. However, it isn't safe if you're expecting a 0 from a mathematical operation.

Comment: what should be the right approach when you want to compare 0 from mathematical operation

Answer (score 5):

You still shouldn't check to see if it's equal to zero. Just check to see if it's near zero.

```
private final static double EPSILON = 0.00001;
if (x + EPSILON > 0 && x - EPSILON < 0){
...
}
```

Comment: You should not use an absolute epison but a relative one.  E.G., `if (value >= target * (1 - epsilon) && value <= target * (1 + epsilon ))` This is especially true when the values can vary over a large range.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This will work only if target is positive.

Answer (score 4):

if you set it yourself and wish to see if it ever changed you can safely check for equality (like using a sentinel value) though NaN is safer for things like that

```
float x=Float.NaN;
{
   //some code that may or may not set x
}
if(Float.isNaN(x))//it never got set
```

Answer (score 1):

double has positive and negative zero. `==` between positive zero and negative zero returns false. Also, `==` betwen two NaNs returns false.

Comment: You're wrong. Negative zero compares equal to positive zero. This is required by the IEEE-794 standard, which Java follows.