# QMap Memory Error

Tags: qt, memory, qmap

I am doing one project in which I define a data types like below

```
typedef QVector<double> QFilterDataMap1D;

typedef QMap<double, QFilterDataMap1D> QFilterDataMap2D;
```

Then there is one class with the name of mono_data in which i have define this variable

```
QFilterMap2D valid_filters;



mono_data Scan_data // Class
```

Now i am reading one variable from a .mat file and trying to save it in to above "valid_filters" QMap.

Qt Code: Switch view

```
for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
        {
            Scan_Data.valid_filters[i][j]=valid_filters[i][j];
            printf("\nValid_filters=%f",Scan_Data.valid_filters[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

The transferring is done successfully but then it gives run-time error

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in SpectralDataCollector.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, and indicates a bug in
>   SpectralDataCollector.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> The output window may have more diagnostic information

Can anyone help in solving this problem. It will be of great help to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different issues here:

**1. Using double as key type for a QMap**

Using a `QMap<double, Foo>` is a very bad idea. the reason is that this is a container that let you access a `Foo` given a `double`. For instance:

```
map[0.45] = foo1;
map[15.74] = foo2;
```

This is problematic, because then, to retrieve the data contained in `map[key]`, you have to test if `key` is either equal, smaller or greater than other keys in the maps. In your case, the key is a `double`, and testing if two `double`s are equals [is not a "safe" operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180952/is-checking-a-double-for-equality-ever-safe-java).

**2. Using an int as key while you defined it was double**

Here:

```
Scan_Data.valid_filters[i][j]=valid_filters[i][j];
```

`i` is an integer, and you said it should be a double.

**3. Your loop only test for (i,j) = (0,0)**

Are you aware that

```
for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
    {
        Scan_Data.valid_filters[i][j]=valid_filters[i][j];
        printf("\nValid_filters=%f",Scan_Data.valid_filters[i][j]);
    }
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
Scan_Data.valid_filters[0][0]=valid_filters[0][0];
printf("\nValid_filters=%f",Scan_Data.valid_filters[0][0]);
```

?

**4. Accessing a vector with operator[] is not safe**

When you do:

```
Scan_Data.valid_filters[i][j]
```

You in fact do:

```
QFilterDataMap1D & v = Scan_Data.valid_filters[i]; // call QMap::operator[](double)
double             d = v[j];                       // call QVector::operator[](int)
```

The first one is safe, and create the entry if it doesn't exist. The second one is not safe, the jth element in you vector must already exist otherwise it would crash.

**Solution**

It seems you in fact want a 2D array of double (i.e., a matrix). To do this, use:

```
typedef QVector<double> QFilterDataMap1D;
typedef QVector<QFilterDataMap1D> QFilterDataMap2D;
```

Then, when you want to transfer one in another, simply use:

```
Scan_Data.valid_filters = valid_filters;
```

Or if you want to do it yourself:

```
Scan_Data.valid_filters.clear();
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    Scan_Data.valid_filters << QFilterDataMap1D();
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        Scan_Data.valid_filters[i] << valid_filters[i][j];
        printf("\nValid_filters=%f",Scan_Data.valid_filters[i][j]);
    }
}
```

If you want a 3D matrix, you would use:

```
typedef QVector<QFilterDataMap2D> QFilterDataMap3D;
```

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for the reply. For the 3rd part, yeah i know that they are equivalent..actually my matrix size is 1*900..i was just checking it with 1*1. for the solution part, i modified it little and it is working great. can you please give me some advice how i can write code for 3d?
    typedef QVector<double> QFilterDataMap1D;
    typedef QMap<double, QFilterDataMap1D> QFilterDataMap2D; 
    typedef QMap<double, QFilterDataMap2D> QFilterDataMap3D;

Comment: @Saad Ok, glad it helped :-) Yes, what you propose is fine. If you need more efficiency though, you may want in fact to use a 1D vector of size sizeX * sizeY * sizeZ, and access the elements with myEmulated3DArray[i*sizeY*sizeZ + j*sizeZ + k]. This later approach is better for a variety of reason, but I would say don't worry about it now, go with the simplest approach :)

Comment: @Saad. Oh no, I just realized you used QMap again. No! Forget about QMap, you are misleaded by the name, this really isn't what you need. :) For a 3D matrix, use: `QVector< QVector< QVector<double> > >`

Comment: If i am not wrong then this is right or wrong syntax?typedef QVector<double, QFilterDataMap1D> QFilterDataMap2D;

Comment: @Saad, My bad, I did a mistake in my answer due to copy-pasting. This syntax is wrong, remove the `double`, see in 1min my updated answer.

Comment: Of course the notion that comparison of doubles is somehow "unsafe" is as bogus as it gets. A double is simply a binary representation of an exponent, a sign and a mantissa. If you have two of them and they have the same value, they compare equal. If they don't have the same value, the compare unequal. There's no magic to it, so please, let's not propagate bogosity. Now if you're asking whether it's always easy to produce the very value you intend to - now that may be harder, but it's of no consequence here. It really depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Dear Boris..Can you please on this new thread started by me...this is also regarding qt and i am hopeful that you will help me in this also.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626426/qstring-to-string-and-vica-versa..