# How can I prevent my Javafx Pane from resizing to fit it's children

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, pane

I am currently using JavaFX `Pane` and have a ball class (an `Imageview`) within it that I want to bounce off the edges of it like is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022889/how-to-make-the-ball-bounce-off-the-walls-in-javafx) however the `minX` of the Pane seems to get smaller as the ball goes off the edge of it.

It seems the `Pane` resizes to fit all the nodes added to it, meaning I can't ever check if the ball goes off the left side of the `Pane`. Is there a way to prevent this resizing or a better way to check the edges of the Pane?

Comment: work through a tutorial about how to use layouts - when stuck come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's wrong

Comment: [bouncing ball app](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842)

Comment: “the minX of the Pane seems to get smaller as the ball goes off the edge of it” -> don’t let the ball go off the edge.

Comment: Another example: [breakout game](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/910dae32ef6d1bd4257850031aefcba2) (more complex).

Comment: @jewelsea so from what you're saying/your second example I'm getting the impression that Panes always resize? As in there's no way to really get the bounds without just extracting them out into a second object at creation?

Comment: @MakoriSM No, that’s not what I think jewelsea is saying. If you check the current bounds of the pane when you love the ball, and just don’t move the ball outside those bounds, then the bounds should never change.

Comment: Read the links and try to implement it the same way. If you can’t do it, create and post a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @James_D I'm able to do it in that way, but that's a different implementation to the one I proposed, one that only is necessary if my assumption that "you can't check the ball once it has gone off the edge because the Pane will always resize" is true. I want to know if there is no way to prevent this Pane resizing.

Comment: @MakoriSM “Move it and then move it back if it moved off the edge of the pane”, as compared to “move it only if moving it doesn’t move it off the edge of the pane” just seems like a terrible choice anyway. It’s not really possible to answer the question you’re asking without more information though.